# how to test login command in unix using shell script?

Tags: shell-script, login

IN shell scripting I am using as : sudo login $user && echo 'yes'
and expecting "yes" as output.
But its not as per expectation.

****Actually my task is to automate "login" command to test in Linux.****

Comment: I remember using something called `expect` to supress the interactivity of login

Comment: I want to validate login command. How to pass exit command here. So that after login successfully it should exit and print "logout\nyes".

Comment: `expect` is your solution. It's sorta like login command->expect the login creds-> print something -> logout. This should work for your script.

Comment: I tried like this, but couldn't find to put in script.$ sudo login $user && expect
Password:
Last login: ......
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

7 packages can be updated.
7 updates are security updates.

:~$ exit
logout
expect1.1> hi
     1  hi
expect1.2> exit
$

Comment: @ash.k29 I tried in diff way using expect but no luck till now. Have you tried the way you were telling? And the login creds cant be given in expect I think.

Comment: I've seen it used in remote logins... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226563/using-expect-script-to-do-an-ssh-from-a-remote-machine is an example.

Comment: If the `login` command succeeds, it overlays itself with the user's shell. When the shell exits, it does not necessarily return 0 (success).

Comment: That's true. still struggling with the test suite to validate login command.